# Trigger $scope.$watch into AngularJS directive with the same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following ambiguity. I write AngularJS directive and use $scope.$watch into it.
When there is change on  watched value I made several DOM manipulations into directive. 
This is me code (only important parts):

```
compile: function (tElement) {

    return function link($scope, element) {


        $scope.$watch("watchedvalue", function (value) {
            /**
             *  Here I constructing several DOM object 
             * according to the value
             **/
        });

    }
}
```

The main problem is how to trigger $scope.$watch with the same value. I tried with $scope.$apply() with no luck. When the value is different, everything works as it should. I also try to delete with with

```
if(typeof $scope.watchedvalue != 'undefined') {
    delete $scope.watchedvalue;
}
```

And after this set old value again. But this not help also.

Comment: So you want to trigger a `$watch` event when the value...stays the same? I don't understand.

Comment: In the fact - yes. I want to rebuild dom structure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think the question makes sense (at least not without more information). `watchedvalue` is "not changing" almost all of the time, so if you rebuilt the DOM every time it didn't change, you would never stop updating the DOM. Can you give a more clear explanation of _when_ you want to rebuild the DOM?